# Не могу разобраться, стоит ли здесь ставить тире

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, тире

Речь, какой бы она великой и ученной ни была — не оставляет больших следов ни в сознании слушателя, ни в культурном контексте, в отличие от письменности.

Comment: https://obrazovaka.ru/question/kakim-by-ni-byl-ili-ne-byl-kak-pravilno-125648#:~:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%E2%80%93%20%C2%AB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%B1%D1%8B,%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C.

Comment: И ещё в эту бочку мёда: поскольку предлог, то пишется **в отличие**.

Comment: Благодарю, но вот тире всё-таки может кто-то прокомментировать?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы оформила это предложение следующим образом:
*Речь (какой бы великой и ученой она ни была) не оставляет больших следов ни в сознании слушателя, ни в культурном контексте - в отличие от письменности.*

Answer (score 1):

Для начала:
[учё**н**ый](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) — прилагательное, пишется с одной буквой "н";
[какой бы **ни** была](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/126-gl-19-13) — частица ***ни*** употребляется перед сказуемым в придаточных предложениях для усиления утвердительного смысла, например: *Какой бы **ни** была жизнь вокруг, оправданий нет и не предвидится* (Сергей Лукьяненко. Ночной дозор);
[в отличи**е**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5) — предлог (от кого, от чего), в отличие от письменности.

Здесь, считаю, нужны парные знаки:
*Речь, **какой бы она великой и ученой ни была,** не оставляет больших следов ни в сознании слушателя, ни в культурном контексте, в отличие от письменности.*

> Как дерево не может жить без корней, так и страна, **какой бы великой она ни была,** не может нормально развиваться, не имея своего, только ей присущего героического прошлого, откуда черпает она силы и мудрость дальнейшего движения вперед.
> А. Фоменко

Если по контексту необходимо каким-то образом подчеркнуть или выделить указанное придаточное, то  можно использовать тире или скобки.